# How do I make my first Tab rotate and others not on my iOS 7 application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rotation, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` set up in Interface Builder and it has five tabs. I want the first tab to be able to rotate left or right, but all of the other tabs should not be rotatable and only be set to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.

I put this code in my second tab's view controller (one that shouldn't rotate at all) but it still does. Stepping through the code it's being called correctly as expected, but the screen rotates anyway. Any ideas why this may be?

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by subclassing UITabBarController and adding the code in there.